# Hibernate save() not saving html tags to database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, dao

I can't able to save html tags to mysql database as string, below is hibernate code.

```
RemovalCompany companyToUpdate = removalCompanyDao.getEager(removalCompanyId);
companyToUpdate.setDescription("<h1>Welcome</h1>");
companyToUpdate.setRating(1);
companyToUpdate.setNumberOfReviews(12);
removalCompanyDao.save(companyToUpdate);
```

Save is working, only `'Welcome'` is storing into database, `<h1></h1>` tags are not saving.
Help me out, if anyone came across similar problem.

Comment: That's simply not possible. The tool, or the code you're using to display what the description contains is the one that most probably hides or removes the HTML code. How are you retrieving and displaying this value?

Comment: Add few debugs just ater fetching from DB. As @JBNizet mentioned its not possible its with DB.

Comment: hi @JBNizet actually already some html data is stored in that description field, but when i am trying to update reviews and rating the description field updating as plain text.

Comment: @ChennaReddy in log its displaying as `<h1>Welcome</h1>` but while saving only its saving just `Welcome`.

Comment: Is it the log after fetch/query from DB? or before save to DB?

Comment: before saving to DB @ChennaReddy.

Comment: add a log after fetch, so that you can be sure its not a problem with DB (or it is), then debug further

Comment: fetching is not problem while updating the field am not able to save the data with html tags.

Comment: So how do you know that it didn't save the html tags, when you don't fetch it?

Comment: i can check DB, and `RemovalCompany companyToUpdate = removalCompanyDao.getEager(removalCompanyId);` this line will get the details.  this problem is happenning when trying to update

Comment: And you are sure that the html tags are not escaped by the tool which you use to check your DB? Also you said, that it happens, while only updating rating and numberOfReviews. So you use actually different kind of code to update your record, is that right? Could it happen, that you just get the description as plaintext before setting it in the description field?

Comment: `companyToUpdate.getDescription()` will return the html text like `<h1>World<h1>`
but if i use `companyToUpdate.setDescription(companyToUpdate.getDescription())` then also its will just save "World" in DB.

Comment: Then you have an error somewhere else in your code. The behaviour you described with the code examples is simply not possible.

Comment: @dunni there was no error. its ok, somehow i written native query to update, thank you.